# excel vba function to return recordset

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

I have a VBA function that returns a `RecordSet` and this `RecordSet` is used in a subroutine. The function itself lives in a module. Whilst the function itself returns a `RecordSet` successfully, I have two problems:

1. If I try to close the connection in the function, it causes the application to fail
2. If I try to close the `RecordSet` in the subroutine after using it, it causes the application to fail

So, how do I close a connection in a function after returning a recordset and close a recordset after using it?

My function makes a connection, opens its, and executes the query.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Recordsets depend on a live connection to work. You shouldn't try to close the connection until you are done with any recordset you are using.

Answer (score 0):

After using the recordset it must be closed.

When a recordset is active it consumes resources. After using the recordset you should free the memory it was using so they can be made available to other objects of the computer. This is done by assing Nothing to the Recordset object. Here is an example:

```
'Clean Up
rsTemp.Close 'closing recordset
Set rsTemp= Nothing ' free the memory
```

Also you may close the connection at the end.

```
If con.State = adStateOpen Then
 con.Close
End If

If Not con Is Nothing Then Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: In the function that returns the recordset, if I set the recordset and connection to nothing or to close, the code will fail and nothing be returned to the calling subroutine. I have tried closing the set recordset that is used in the calling subroutine, but as I said it fails.Where do you put in the subroutine the closing of the recordset as to not make it fail and close the connection in the function as to not cause it to fail?

Comment: @Andy5 You can create a function which recordset. Let the function return the recordset ....consume the recordset in the calling function and then you close the recordset.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it as a function. Modulise out into a subroutine